# Show "Add to Cart" and "Add to Wishlist" buttons in Recently Viewed Products block

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want to display "Add to cart" and "Add to wishlist" buttons under products displaying in Recently Viewed section.

product_viewed.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
                </a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your file as per below code

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
                </a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>

                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>

                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_item) ?>')">
                         <span>
                             <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                         </span>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thankl you for your answer. But, can you tell me in which file should I make changes?

Comment: where you are showing recently viewed products?

Comment: I am showing that on my cart page.

Comment: add your .phtml file(recently viewed .phtml)

Comment: In default magento only crosscell products are showing in cart page. Recently viewed by default not coming. You can enable template path hints and see which template file it is using ?

Comment: In cart.phtml, I have added following code to show recently viwed products:
<?php
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("reports/product_viewed")->setTemplate("reports/product_viewed.phtml")->toHtml();
?>

Comment: post product_viewed.phtml file code here

Comment: I have added product_viewed.phtml

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Yes add to cart and add to wishlist buttons are there. But, when I click on add to cart then product is added tyo cart via ajax (I am using Ajaxcart extension) and then one more block of recently viewed products is appended. do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok. its depend on how your ajax add to cart response is managed by ajaxcart extension. you will need to little bit debug that module and you will be able to solve it.